# Data access layer assembly reference chain

Tags: .net, entity-framework, sql-server-ce, data-access-layer

I have a DataAccess assembly refering to the SQL Server Compact dlls.

From my main app I just add a reference to DataAccess assembly. I'd like my main app not to have any reference to any dll referenced by DataAccess internally, specifically a reference to SQL Server Compact assemblies, so that if I change to another provider I don't have to change reference in the main project or update `app.config` configuration.

By the way at runtime I get the following error:

> No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient'.
>   Make sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the application config file.
>   See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.

If I directly add a reference to SQL Server Compact everything works fine but I don't think I should do that.

If I copy all dlls used by DataAccess into main app output folder everything works fine, but should't dlls be copied automatically?

What's the right way to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

In your solution:

- Find *DataAccess* project.
- Expand *References* node for this project.
- Find *SqlServerCompact* on the list of references.
- Right click it.
- Change *Copy Local* from *False* to *True*.

**UPDATE**

I was able to reproduce your problem. It seems to me that a reason behind it is that in *DataAccess* project you are not using directly classes from *SQL Server Compact* assembly. In this case a build engine tries to be smart and doesn't copy assemblies that ''are not used''. However, it takes into account only a source code and not a configuration. There is a great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21055626/460363) about this problem worth reading. The suggested solution is to add a dummy code that directly uses *SQL Server Compact* assembly. This code (placed somewhere in *DataAccess* project) should worke:

```
var t = typeof (System.Data.Entity.SqlServerCompact.SqlCeFunctions)
```

Comment: it is already set to true for EntityFramework, EntityFramework.SqlServer and EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact. I'm using nuget.

Comment: Thank you! I found out the same things you wrote in the update independently so i'm confident the problem is exactly that. By the way I don't like the dummy code solution. I'm investigating the possibility to make the DataAccess agnostic and configure which provider to use from the main application app.config. Do you think is that possible? To test this possibility I'm trying to switch from the main app from SqlServerCe to SqlLite without touching DataAccess assembly and have things working. Any further help to end up with a better solution than dummy code is greatly appreaciated.