# Fsharp.Core dependency from nuget package doesn't get copied to bin directory

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, f#, nuget

I'm using ExcelFinancialFunctions nuget package in a C# library (DLL) project (let's call it **A**), that project **A** is referenced by project **B**, And I have a unit tests project **C** that references project **B**

So the dependency path is **C** > **B** > **A**

ExcelFinancialFunctions depends on Fsharp.Core.

Now when I build project **C**, Fsharp.Core.dll gets copied to bin directory of project **A** with ExcelFinancialFunctions.dll, but it's not the case for projects **B** and **C**; their bin directory has ExcelFinancialFunctions.dll only and that causes a runtime error whenever any function in ExcelFinancialFunctions.dll is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the steps in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19527284/nuget-packages-not-copied-from-referenced-project/19889803#19889803) and found there's a problem in binding the version of FSharp.Core, so I added the piece below to the unit test project app.config

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="FSharp.Core" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="4.4.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

so 4.4.0.0 is the version downloaded with the the Nuget package, and I'm doing range (0-5) redirect, because in the output window of the build, I saw a step trying to load a version higher than 4.4.0.0, probably trying to load it from the installed .NET SDK (I have .NET Framework 4.7.2, didn't investigate the reason it tries to load a higher version though)

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here, you could accept it as an answer. This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread.

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT thanks. I marked it as accepted. I hope someone can provide the reason why it is trying to load a higher version.